# Is importing headings from an Access database possible?

Tags: pandas, database, python-2.7, dataframe, ms-access

Is there a way to import headings from an Access database into a dataframe?

Due to a number of tables and lots of headings, I don't want to type out the heading for each column.

I can't find a solution anywhere :(

Comment: What do you mean with headings? Column names? Then just `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE FALSE` using `readsql` to get a 0-row data frame containing the column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortantly, the Access data engine (JET or now ACE) does not have a command to return the table structure (schema) as a query. Most databases have this feature, but not Access.

There are several solutions:

```
Write some code in VBA + Access.
Write some code in your favorite tool - but it WILL have to support COM object automation.
```

However, you could consider using Access, and the database "documenter". This is able to output a columnar format of each table.

[image]

The output from above looks like this:

So, you can then export that out to a text file, or whatever.

[image]